# J2me synchronization of methods

Tags: java-me, synchronize

I initializing a variable in my startApp method and after I do so I call a thread to check the whole run time of the app what is the current screen (canvas) and activating it's thread

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import zuma.core.MyGameCanvas;
import zuma.core.Game;
import zuma.gui.LevelSelectionMenu;
import zuma.gui.MainMenu;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.MediaException;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import zuma.util.AudioManager;

public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements Runnable{

    private static Display display;
    private static Game game;
    private static MainMenu mainMenu;
    private static LevelSelectionMenu levelSelectionMenu;
    private static MyGameCanvas myGameCanvas;
    private Thread t;

    /**
     * Specifies what happens when starting the application.
     */
    public void startApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        display.setCurrent(getMainMenu());
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    /**
     * Specifies what happens when pausing the application.
     */
    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    /**
     * Specifies what happens when exiting the application.
     * @param unconditional 
     */
    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        //game.getLevelsRecordStore().closeRecordStore();
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the display.
     */
    public static Display getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the game.
     */
    public static Game getGame() {
        if (game == null) { //|| game.getLevels() == null) {
            game = new Game();
        }
        return game;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the mainMenu.
     */
    public static synchronized MainMenu getMainMenu() {
        if (mainMenu == null) {
            mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        }
        return mainMenu;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the levelSelectionMenu.
     */
    public static LevelSelectionMenu getLevelSelectionMenu() {
        if (levelSelectionMenu == null) {
            levelSelectionMenu = new LevelSelectionMenu(getGame());
        }
        return levelSelectionMenu;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the myGameCanvas.
     */
    public static MyGameCanvas getMyGameCanvas() {
        if (myGameCanvas == null) {
            myGameCanvas = new MyGameCanvas();
        }
        return myGameCanvas;

    }

    /**
     * Starts the thread of the current display.
     */
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (display.getCurrent().equals(mainMenu)) {
                if (mainMenu.getT() == null || !mainMenu.getT().isAlive()) {
                    mainMenu.init();
                }
                if (getMainMenu().isQuitRequest()) {
                    destroyApp(true);
                }
            }
            else if (display.getCurrent().equals(levelSelectionMenu)) {
                if (levelSelectionMenu.getT() == null || !levelSelectionMenu.getT().isAlive()) {
                    levelSelectionMenu.init();
                }
            }
            else if (display.getCurrent().equals(myGameCanvas)) {
                if (myGameCanvas.getT() == null || !myGameCanvas.getT().isAlive()) {
                    myGameCanvas.init(game.getLevels()[game.getChosenLevel()]);
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Now as you can see I first init the variable mainMenu in this line

```
display.setCurrent(getMainMenu());
```

and only then call run method, but somehow *SOMETIMES* it gives me null pointer exception on this line

```
if (display.getCurrent().equals(mainMenu))
```

so somehow the thread is getting called even before the mainMenu is being created and I have no idea how, what I tried is making the run method and the getMainMenu methos synchronized but it didnt work, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The thread is not getting called before the main menu is created. After setCurrent is called, there is actually a delay before the displayable is made visible. The doc says: *"The setCurrent() method returns immediately, without waiting for the change to take place. Because of this delay, a call to getCurrent() shortly after a call to setCurrent() is unlikely to return the value passed to setCurrent()."*

Comment: so what will be the nicest way to fix it ? Adding a sleep call before starting the thread ?

Comment: Sleep call is dangerous in startApp method, because it is a callback from the system and it should not be blocked for long. I would handle it in the run() method, eg. `if (display.getCurrent() == null) { /* not initialized yet */ } else if display.getCurrent().equals(mainMenu)) { ...`